# How to fix the rectangle size for image cropping?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix the zoom in size for image cropping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437594/how-to-fix-the-zoom-in-size-for-image-cropping)

In my app,user can select image from gallery and after that he can zoom in/ zoom out that image .I want to fix the height and width of rectangle while zoom in for image cropping.How to do this?I tried a lot but still not able to solve the problem.Please someone help me for my this issue.I tried this.

```
//intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 3);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 4);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

Comment: have u got the answer. How to solve frame re sizing problem when cropping rectangle image.+1 for your question.please post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null)
        .setType("image/*")
        .putExtra("crop", "true")
        .putExtra("aspectX", width)
        .putExtra("aspectY", height)
        .putExtra("outputX", width)
        .putExtra("outputY", height)
        .putExtra("scale", true)
        .putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true)
        .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f))
        .putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
```

Comment: What is the exact meaning of aspectX and aspectY?

Comment: Setting the aspectX and aspectY will force the android to move both sides of the shape when you move one of them. Comment those lines and you'll be free to move the shape.

Comment: how to fix the rectangle size while zooming for image cropping?

Comment: Romil, Have you got answer to fix size of the rectangle?

Comment: i have tried this...couldn't get proper thing that i want?