# How to fix the zoom in size for image cropping?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to fix the zoom in size for image cropping.How to do this?I found a lot and tried a lot but still not able to get the right solution yet.cropped image too much zoomed and getting blurre.Please someone help me for my this issue.my code is.

```
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 300);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 300);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", false);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
intent.putExtra("outputX", 200); //Set this to define the max size of the output bitmap
intent.putExtra("outputY", 200); //Set this to define the max size of the output bitmap
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1); //Set this to define the X aspect ratio of the shape
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1); //Set this to define the Y aspect ratio of the shape
```

check this [link](http://walletapp.net/en/cookbook/crop-image)

Comment: I tried it but still not able to solve the problem.I want to fix the Rectangle size while zoom in.How to do that?